# The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. while getting the website into stream reader

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest, streamreader, getresponsestream

I'm getting an error at

```
StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
```

saying the remote server returned an error :

> 403 forbidden

I'm passing `http://www.snapdeal.com` in the URL.

```
StreamReader reader = objm.URLServerR(address);   
       public StreamReader URLServerR(string url)
                {
                    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                    StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
                    return stream;
                }
```

Comment: can you access the url via browser ?

Comment: yes i can access through browser

Comment: im able to get some websites into stream reader but not every site like flipkart. @BigMike

Comment: The site refuses your client. Look at their usage policies, you're breaking them.